# How to perform typecasting?

Tags: c

I have a character pointer and i want to display an integer value. Then is is the following statement correct:

```
printf("%d",*(int *)ptr);
```

Can u pls explain me a bit?

Comment: An integer value of what? Of the first character? That it contains as a string?

Comment: Where should this integer value come from? Is the string supposed to contain an integer, i.e. the string "12"? Or do you want the string's ASCII values? Or what?

Comment: Have you explored api atoi(). Which converts string to integer directly

Comment: It's not very clear whether you are trying to print out the value of an integer encoded in a string or simply trying to typecast a number to an signed int. More information on the type of ptr would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If the character pointer (string) points to a valid C-string which stores a number in string format, like `"123"`, simply use the `%s` format specifier.

`printf("%s", ptr);`

The `%d` format specifier is used to print numbers stored as binary signed integers of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's generally wrong because a `char` is only 1 byte while an `int` is typically 4 bytes. The remaining bytes that you access may be invalid depending on what it points to, and this can undefined behaviour. The correct way to do it would be to get the `char` value first and then cast it to an `int`:

```
(int)*ptr
```

Of course, in this case, an explicit cast may not be necessary at all, as the character value will implicitly get promoted to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what type the variable ptr has been declared to be.

If it was declared int *ptr; then only a de-reference would be required

ie. printf("%d", *ptr);

because ptr is of type int*, and *ptr is therefore of type int, which matches %d

However, I'm guessing ptr was declared void * ptr; in your example, in which case
if you know it actually points to an int, then casting from the generic pointer
type to int* is correct before then de-referencing.

ie. printf("%d", *(int * )ptr);